# Cyclic inheritance and interfaces - class A can't implement class B interface while class B implements A interface

Tags: java, android, inheritance, interface, implements

I have:

```
public class A implements BListener {
    public interface AListener {}
}

public class B implements AListener {
    public interface BListener {}
}
```

So, if I understand correctly the cyclic inheritance happens because:

The compiler goes to **A** and says *"hey, A implements BListener, let's go find BListener!"*

Then when it tries to find BListener, it eventually gets to **B**, which it says:

*"Hey, BListener, needed for A is inside B! BUT WAIT! B needs AListener! Let's go find AListener!"*

And then it gets to A, repeat. Did I get this right?

By the way, this compilation error happened to me on Android development.

Comment: Why did this question get a negative?

Comment: _this happened_ What is _this_? Did you get a compilation error? Which compilation error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It may help to draw it out.

```
              >A 
is part of  /     \    inherits
                   V             
   AListener        BListener
           ^
  inherits  \     /    is part of 
               B<
```

A lovely circle. You can't create one of them without the others already existing.

> Is the compiler a squirrel with ADHD high on coffee chasing it's own tail?

Nope because a the squirrel would not stop (until the caffeine ran out). The compiler looks for this and then gives up.

Note: Eclipse has a bug which allows this setup.

Comment: It's a very determined squirrel! Thanks, then I got it right. Accepting in 7 minutes.

Comment: re "is part of"; Aren't interfaces supposed to be static?

Answer (score 2):

After further investigation, I was initially wrong.

The technical explanation for the behavior you are noticing is the following

From the Java Language Specification chapter on [Superclasses and subclasses](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.4)

> A class `C` directly depends on a type `T` if `T` is mentioned in the
>   `extends` or `implements` clause of `C` either as a superclass or
>   superinterface, or as a qualifier in the fully qualified form of a
>   superclass or superinterface name.
>
> A class `C` depends on a reference type `T` if any of the following is
>   true:
>
> - `C` directly depends on `T`.
> - `C` directly depends on an interface `I` that depends (§9.1.3) on `T`.
> - `C` directly depends on a class `D` that depends on `T` (using this definition recursively).
>
> **It is a compile-time error if a class depends on itself.**

Let's take your code, with fully qualified names for type uses, assuming the classes were declared in package `com.example`:

```
public class A implements com.example.B.BListener {
    public interface AListener {}
}

public class B implements com.example.A.AListener {
    public interface BListener {}
}
```

Following the rules from the JLS above

- `A` directly depends on `BListener`, because it's mentioned in its `implements` clause.
- `A` directly depends on `B`, because it's mentioned as a qualifier in the fully qualified name of a superinterface (`BListener` is `com.example.B.BListener`)
- `B` directly depends on `AListener`, because it's mentioned in its `implements` clause.
- `B` directly depends on `A`, because it's mentioned as a qualifier in the fully qualified name of a superinterface (`AListener` is `com.example.A.AListener`)
- `A` directly depends on `B` that depends on `A`.

Therefore `A` depends on `A` and a compilation error should occur.

---

In Eclipse, the error occurs if you qualify the names

```
class A implements B.BListener {
    public static interface AListener {
    }
}

class B implements A.AListener {
    public static interface BListener {
    }
}
```

If you use `import` statements, however, it doesn't. I'll be opening a bug with them.

Comment: I'm still getting "cyclic inheritance involving com.example.B" in intelliJ.

Comment: And in Maven. `[ERROR] /home/mlk/code/test_project/src/test/java/com/example/A.java:[4,7] error: cyclic inheritance involving A`

Comment: @mlk I might be wrong, here. Eclipse compiles this without issue. I'm going to investigate further.

Comment: @mlk 8, but I don't think that matters. This process hasn't changed afaik.

Comment: @mlk Yeah, looks like [compilers diverging in behavior](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8928456/why-does-this-code-compile-with-eclipse-compiler-but-not-with-javac-maven)

Comment: I'm using AndroidStudio. It whines as soon as I finish writing the code.

Comment: Android Studio is based of Idea. Your options are to take the interfaces out of `A` and `B` (probs a good idea anyway) or change the compiler IDEA uses so it uses the Eclipse compiler (a very bad idea IMO) or switch to Eclipse (also IMO a bad idea as any other developer (and the build server) will also have to change as you are using a none-standard feature.

Comment: @mlk This is a bug in Eclipse after investigating the JLS. It's more evident with qualified names in `implements` clauses. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: @NotGabriel I've updated my answer. I was previously going off contradictory behavior I was seeing on Eclipse.

Comment: @mlk Yah, I just moved the interface out of the class. I'd rather have it inside though. Why do you say it's a good idea to not have inner interfaces?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Hm I see. But since I'm not using Eclipse's compiler, I guess I won't be able to do much except moving the interfaces out of the class.

Comment: @NotGabriel You can't do what you are currently doing. I don't know what your end goal is so it's hard to tell you what your options are.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I simply needed some listeners for my Toolbar. I use a single toolbar in a FragmentActivity and Fragments sometimes have to attach events to the toolbar's widgets. I mean, simply moving the interface out of the class solved it, pretty simple, just not very pretty. I could transform the Toolbar in a widget (It's simply a ViewGroup now), add interfaces in the toolbar... I don't know, sounds like an overkill solution. I'll tackle this later :p