# Java Outer Class extends static Inner Class

Tags: java, inheritance, inner-classes

This is allowed:

```
public class Outer {
    public static class Inner extends Outer { }
}
```

but this is not:

```
public class Outer extends Inner {
    public static class Inner { }
}
```

In the second case the compiler complains of `Cyclic inheritance involving package.Outer`. I don't see any cycles involved; why is the second case not valid?

This behaves the same whether Inner is `class`, `abstract class`, or `interface`.

The use case is for a recursive data structure -- a symbol namespace. Basically, I want the naming structure of `Namespace extends Namespace.Member`, `MyDataChunk extends Namespace.Member`; each `Namespace` would act like a map from `String` to `Namespace.Member`, thus allowing recursing down multiple levels of `Namespace` terminating with a `MyDataChunk`.

Comment: You don't see any cycles, yet, this is for a recursive data-structure. This seems to be contradicting. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33918022/cyclic-inheritance-and-interfaces-class-a-cant-implement-class-b-interface-wh

Comment: @Tunaki If I'm reading it right, The types shouldn't be cycling; the actual recursion isn't even in yet (a member of `Map<String, Member>`).

Comment: @Tunaki Cyclic inheritance is `A extends B` and `B extends A`, and a recursive data structure is `A { member A }`. As of the above code, neither should be present if I'm reading correctly, though the compiler complains of the former.

Comment: No, you get a mixed cycle here: outer class inherits from nested class and nested class is member of outer class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I don't see any cycles involved

I do: `Outer` can't extend `Outer.Inner` if it doesn't exist. For `Outer.Inner` to exist, `Outer` has to exist. It's a Catch-22, a cyclic dependency.

Comment: This becomes even more obvious if we call the nested class a `member type` as the [JLS does](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.6).

Comment: That does make sense; I thought it wouldn't behave that way with `static`. That's why I asked!