# In Java, why can a class not implement its inner interface?

Tags: java, interface

In the following code, Android Studio throws an error saying that this involved cyclic inheritance. I don't understand why this is occurring. The enclosing class can be abstract or final or none but the error remains.

```
public abstract class BaseDataModel
    extends BaseModel
    implements BaseDataModel.IMapper<BaseEntity> {

    public interface IMapper<E extends BaseEntity> {
        default E map() { throw new UnsupportedOperationException();}
    }
}
```

In short, why can a class in Java not implement its inner interface?

Edit: Although, this question is not an exact duplicate of [Cyclic inheritance and interfaces - class A can't implement class B interface while class B implements A interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33918022/cyclic-inheritance-and-interfaces-class-a-cant-implement-class-b-interface-wh) , the solution given there answers this one as well, ie a class cannot depend on itself.

Comment: I don't fully understand your comment. If an  inner class can only be instantiated through a instance of the outer class, shouldn't an instance of the enclosing class be able to implement the inner interface?

Comment: The out class needs to be able to be instantiated first, in your example, it'd be trying to create an instance of the inner class first, but it can't because it can't instantiated the outer class, it's a vicious circle.  Again, I'm not sure it entirely makes conceptual sense to try and do it that way anyway

Comment: But the inner class is static. You mean the outer class will be loaded first to load the inner class, so the outer class can not implement inner interface / extend inner class?

Comment: Based on the `cyclic inheritance` error, yes

Comment: Hmm, makes sense. Although, instantiating and loading are different things, I am sure you would know. And it makes sense that the interface can only be loaded once the outer class is, and the outer class requires the interface to be loaded.

Comment: Interesting question. I can't find this specified in the JLS. It's ok to have a superclass or interface that is *parameterized* on a member class. The JVM wouldn't mind if you implement your own member interface - it's syntactic sugar in any case. Not clear why both javac and the Eclipse compiler disallow it.

Comment: Although on verification, it seems that after compilation, the outer class and inner interface are independent. So we are back to square one.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt what do you mean by syntactic sugar?

Comment: Syntactic sugar: member classes and other inner classes are only known to the Java Compiler. The JVM doesn't know about the concept, it only sees interesting class names like `mypackage.BaseDataModel$IMapper`. The only cycle that the JVM cares about is whether a class directly or indirectly extends itself, but the JVM couldn't care less whether you implemented or extended a member class or not.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt true. Earlier I thought an inner class can be loaded only after the outer class has been, but after compilation, both are independent, so that is not the case either.

Comment: Both 'inner interface' and 'but the inner class is static' are contradictions in terms. Not that there are any inner classes here.